# How does the determinant containing cube root of unity and real numbers a,b,c represent a straight line?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

[image]

The answers says it's **Option D**.

Solving the determinant, I get:
$$ \omega(c\omega+b) + a -c=0 $$

How does the above equation corresponds to a straight line?

I tried to simplify further by substituting the value of $\omega$ but that just gave me the relation $ a= 2c, b = c$. I don't understand it further.

Can you please help?

Comment: But $(a,b,c)=(2c,c,c)$ describes a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so you have proven it's $D$? In particular it's the line through the origin parallel to the vector $(2,1,1)$.

Comment: How is it a straight line? Shouldn't it be a point?

Comment: No because $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary parameter.

Comment: okay so u mean , in general $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ means $(x,y,z) $ reppresents a vector/straight line, right?

Comment: No what you just wrote means $(x,y,z)$ is an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'm stating that you have shown this set contains only elements of the form $(2c,c,c)$ and hence forms a straight line.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!